# Recover data after transferring data between two phones with 3utools

Tags: iphone, memory, backup, photo, restore

After taking a backup, all the data will be deleted and the phone will return to the factory reset stage, or can the data be restored?

Hey, I bought a new phone and backed up my iPhone 8 and transferred the data to the iPhone 14. Now the photos I took with iPhone 14 are deleted. Is there a way to get my photo back or will it be completely deleted? Does anyone have experience to guide me?